# Possible Java1.8 stream anomaly

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can someone explain the behavior of the following code? In particular why does the forEach in the stream change the original List?:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class foreachIssue {
        class justanInt {   
        public int anint; 
        public justanInt(int t){
            anint=t;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new foreachIssue();
    }
    public foreachIssue(){
        System.out.println("The Stream Output:"); 
        List<justanInt> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        justanInt j1=new justanInt(2);
        justanInt j2=new justanInt(5);
        lst.add(j1);lst.add(j2);
        lst.stream()
                .map((s)->{
                    s.anint=s.anint*s.anint;
                    return s;
                })
                .forEach((s)->System.out.println("Anything"));
        System.out.println(" lst after the stream:"); 
        for(justanInt il:lst)
            System.out.println(il.anint); 

        List<justanInt> lst1 = new ArrayList<>();
        justanInt j3=new justanInt(2);
        justanInt j4=new justanInt(5);
        lst1.add(j3);lst1.add(j4);
        lst1.stream()
                    .map((s)->{
                    s.anint=s.anint*s.anint;
                    return s;
                });
        System.out.println(" lst1 after the stream without forEach:"); 
        for(justanInt il:lst1)
            System.out.println(il.anint); 
    }
}
```

The output is:

The Stream Output:

Anything

Anything

lst after the stream:

4

25

lst1 after the stream without forEach:

2

5

Comment: Refer to JavaDoc, clearly it says map is an intermediate operation.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Is there a reason that I don't get an error or even a warning (in NetBeans) that I am not terminating the stream?

Comment: No reason to get a warning! every intermediate operation returns a Stream object and as long as you don't call terminal operation on that stream you can use the stream. just like writing a line of code like "SubStringReturnAStringNotManipulateTheString".substring(0,1); I'm not saying these mistakes can not be detected but currently only intellijIDE can spot some of these mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

[`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is an [intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

> Stream operations are divided into **intermediate (Stream-producing)
>   operations** and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations.
>   **Intermediate operations are always lazy.**

So the `Function` you've provided to `map` doesn't get applied until you consume the `Stream`. In the first case, you do that with [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), which is a terminal operation. In the second, you don't.

Comment: Side-effecting `Function`s tend to be dangerous and inadvisable, though you can express the operation you're trying to write more accurately with `peek` instead of `map`.

Comment: If it’s supposed to be the terminal operation anyway, `.forEach(s -> s.anint=s.anint*s.anint)` would be the correct solution (and it’s even much simpler…) You can even simplify it further: `.forEach(s -> s.anint*=s.anint)`